# usage of "assumption" and subjunctive mode

Tags: subjunctives

"This was done under the assumption that the car is blue"

OR

"This was done under the assumption that the car be blue" ?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps someone else can provide an authoritative explanation as to *why* only format #1 is likely to be accepted by native speakers. In certain contexts you might read something like ["...the principle that they be treated with respect"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+principle+that+they+be+treated+with+respect%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (note that *assumption, belief, principle, etc.* are syntactically equivalent in such constructions). But that's a rare usage which is unlikely to concern the average learner.

Comment: I would also accept "*... under the assumption that the car was blue.*"   Unless you're speaking *pirate* ;-)  "*Aye, Blackbeard, 'twas done under the assumption that the car be blue.*"

Comment: I vote for @FumbleFingers's comment. The word "assumption" is generally followed by a kind of fact, a kind of condition. So it should be the 1st one, not the 2nd one that states a "to-do" thing (that the car *should* be blue). Unless, like Jim said, you're speaking *pirate*. :)

Comment: @Jim, Safira: Uneducated or "pirate" speech aren't the only credible contexts, as the link in my first comment shows. Personally, I think it probably *is* grammatically "valid" to use plain **be** here - either as a "subjunctive" form, or with an implied preceding *will/would/should* that's been "deleted". It's a rare form, and not something a learner should want to assimilate and repeat in other contexts, but that doesn't make it "wrong" in strictly grammatical terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subjunctive is not required here. And in fact, it should be:

> This **was done** under the assumption that the car **was** blue.

because the doing and the assuming and the car's being blue were all going on at the same point in past time. (Jim says he would "accept" **was**, but I'm going a step further and saying **was** *is correct*, and **is** *is not correct*.)

Answer (score 3):

This is a really difficult one to explain because it depends on what you might mean by "**under the assumption**", which is a polysemous word, which means that it has multiple definitions.  I would say it this way:

> This was done under the assumption that the car **would** be blue
>   [when I received it.]

What do you want to say here?  Here's an example of the subjunctive with **"assume"**.  It is used normally with the past subjunctive (although the present subjunctive is possible, but very formal/archaic) when **"assume"** means **"imagine/suppose"**.  Example:

> Assume I *were* a space alien.  What would you think of me then?

or

> Assuming [that] the house *were* for sale, would you buy it?

I think in the above situation, you want **"under the assumption"** to mean **"provided that"** or **"if"** or **"assuming that"**.  In the future tense (or construction if you should be one who believes English has no future tense), it would be correct and very formal to write it this way:

> This will be done provided that the car *be* blue" or "under the assumption/condition" that the car *be* blue.

I would stay away from your example or use "**would be**" after the "**the car**"; however, it could be "**was**" there as well.  It really just depends on what you might be trying to say herein.  It is confusing without context clues.